# UDP Broadcast on Multihomed Systems

Tags: windows, networking, windows-vista, udp, broadcast

I'm working on a project that discovers/configures remote devices using UDP broadcasts. These devices may not have IP addresses configured yet, at least no to match the network they are connected to. Currently we use a single `sendto` with a target address of `255.255.255.255`. This works fine in most cases but on Vista machines with multiple NICs the broadcast only seems to be sent out one of the interfaces. How can I get Vista to send the broadcast to all interfaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've personally never seen any system generate a packet for every interface in response to a single `sendto` call.

A better option would be to enumerate the network interfaces, determine the correct link-local broadcast and send a separate packet individually via each interface.

Comment: I'm not sure link local addresses will work since not all devices have IP's configured for the link's subnet.

Answer (score 1):

Enumerate the interfaces and then send the packet once on each interface.

Answer (score 1):

We have the exact same problem, only we can't use subnet broadcasts, as we want to configure them. If a device has a wrong IP (outside our range), sending a subnet broadcast to it will never be accepted by its IP stack.
Nasty problem, unless we allow DHCP...

Comment: Actually, we have the same issues